# How do I get Checkstyle CustomImportOrder to work with IntelliJ properly?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, checkstyle

I'm trying to get Checkstyle (via maven-checkstyle-plugin) to have my IntelliJ imports checked by using the Checkstyle CustomImportOrder module. Despite having ordered my imports according to IntelliJ's default rules, Checkstyle still says the import order is wrong.

*Here's my imports (ordered according to IntelliJ rules (ctrl+o):*

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;

import javax.sql.rowset.serial.SQLOutputImpl;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

*Here's the warning message from Checkstyle:*

```
[WARNING] src\main\java\com\example\hej\EnKlass.java[5] (imports) CustomImportOrder: Import statement is in the wrong order. Should be in the 'SPECIAL_IMPORTS' group.
[WARNING] src\main\java\com\example\hej\EnKlass.java[6] (imports) CustomImportOrder: Import statement is in the wrong order. Should be in the 'STANDARD_JAVA_PACKAGE' group.
[WARNING] src\main\java\com\example\hej\EnKlass.java[7] (imports) CustomImportOrder: Import statement is in the wrong order. Should be in the 'STANDARD_JAVA_PACKAGE' group.
```

*Here's my checkstyle.xml CustomImportOrder rules (as recommended for IntelliJ by the Checkstyle site):*

```
<module name="CustomImportOrder">
    <property name="customImportOrderRules" value="THIRD_PARTY_PACKAGE###SPECIAL_IMPORTS###STANDARD_JAVA_PACKAGE###STATIC"/>
    <property name="specialImportsRegExp" value="^javax\."/>
    <property name="standardPackageRegExp" value="^java\."/>
    <property name="sortImportsInGroupAlphabetically" value="true"/>
    <property name="separateLineBetweenGroups" value="false"/>
</module>
```

What might be the problem here? I have been trying to switch the rules around, with no luck. I have also tried to remove/manipulate the regexes with no luck.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Default formatting in IntelliJ looks like as follows:

```
all other imports
<blank line>
javax.* in alphabetical order
java.* in alphabetical order
<blank line>
static imports in alphabetical order
```

Right now, it is not possible to sort `java` and `javax` separately without blank line in-between and that's why you have the violations.

I've raised [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/525) to solve that and it will require changes in Checkstyle code.

As a workaround you may add blank line between `javax` and `java` in IntelliJ IDEA configuration and then it should be easy to tune Checkstyle to work with that.

Comment: Thanks. I figured this was the case. I will let this check be until it's fixed, as we don't want to change any IDEA configuration at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

Don't split `java` and `javax` in separate groups - just let `javax` stand before `java` packages.

**checkstyle.xml:**

```
...
    <module name="CustomImportOrder">
        <property name="customImportOrderRules" value="THIRD_PARTY_PACKAGE###SPECIAL_IMPORTS###STANDARD_JAVA_PACKAGE###STATIC"/>
        <property name="sortImportsInGroupAlphabetically" value="true"/>
        <property name="standardPackageRegExp" value="^(java|javax)\."/>
        <property name="separateLineBetweenGroups" value="true"/>
    </module>
...
```

**checkstyleSuppressions.xml**

```
...
<!--  Let javax.* stand before java.* - that's default Idea settings  -->
<suppress checks="CustomImportOrder"
          message="Wrong lexicographical order for 'java\.[^']+' import\. Should be before 'javax\.[^']+'\."/>
...
```

You can also omit properties that match default values (`standardPackageRegExp` and `separateLineBetweenGroups` for today) - please check actual documentation.